# Android - Logcat doesn't show log activity

Tags: android, debugging, service, logcat

I have my app, and I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that starts a `Service`.

The logs in the receiver are displayed ok but all the logs in the service `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand` and other methods are ignored.

I know they are being executed because breakpoints work Ok, but I can't make logcat to print anything there.

Why can this be happening?

Comment: so show relevant codes sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this was dumb, but may occur to someone so I answer my own question:

The text filter was ON so only some of my texts were showing up.